Geometry nodes not offsetting position by normals properly?
I'm trying to do a simple noise displacement on a sphere in geo nodes, but cant seem to get it to work properly.

notice the blue normal direction, yet the displacement only seems to be diagonal. what am i doing wrong?
thanks :)

You see the link going from Normal to Multiply ? It's a 3d vector at first (violet color) but you are plugging it to a 1d math operator (gray color). This destroys the normal vector down to a scalar value. See John Eason's answer for the correct 3d math operator.

Use a Vector Math node instead of a normal one!

